# Hamcrest assertThat ambiguous?

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest

I got some samplecode from a college, imported the project and try to run the Tests:
The method assertThat(Integer, Matcher) is ambiguous for the type MyClass

Every assertThat is marked red with the same error-message so i tried to write the simpliest test which describes the problem:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@Test
public void whenAssertThatThenItIsAmbiguous() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    assertThat(list.size(), is(3));
}
```

after I scroll over assertThat I get the following message:

```
The method assertThat(Integer, Matcher<Integer>) is ambiguous for the type MyClass
```

I searched google and stackoverflow but couldn't find anybody with the same problem... Please help.

EDIT1:

Solution:

<s>import static org.junit.Assert.*;</s> // delete this line

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both `org.junit.Assert` and `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert` declare `assertThat(T, Matcher<T>)`. Choose to static-import one or the other, but not both, and you should be OK.

Comment: I had same problem with import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*; without having org.junit.Assert inside...

Answer (score 4):

There's two general causes for this, unqualified static imports (`import static blah.*`), or multiple versions of hamcrest on the path.

You may be able to get around it by using the long-form `is(equalTo(3))` (kind of doubt it), culling your static imports, etc.

Which framework you're using it with can matter, too.